# store a location as string, get back location from string to show on a map. iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-location

The limitation is I can only store the location information as string.
I hope to get the current location using coreLocation, then translate it to a string so I can store it in the database. Later on, I hope to get the location information (string format) from the database and show that location on a map. So how can I implement it? Which information of coreLocation I need to store as string? Only latitude and longitude are enough? Then how can I using a string to build a coreLocation, so I can show it on a map? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If your ultimate use of the `CoreLocation` data is for a mapping application, then just latitude and longitude will be sufficient.

Use NSValueTransformer, as such:

```
@interface CLLocationToStringTransformer : NSValueTransformer 
@end

@implementation CLLocationToStringTransformer

+ (BOOL) allowsReverseTransformation 
{ return YES; }

+ (Class) transformedValueClass
{ return [NSString class]; }

- (id) transformedValue: (id) value 
{ CLLocation *location = (CLLocation *) value;
  return [NSString stringWithFormat: "%@ %@",
                   theLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                   theLocation.coordinate.longitude]; } 

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value 
{ NSString *string = (NSString *) value;
  NSArray  *parts  = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
  return [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: [parts[0] doubleValue]
                                    longitude: [parts[1] doubleValue]]; }
@end
```

Comment: Here is a corrected Version of transformedValue: method:

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
        CLLocation *location = (CLLocation *) value;
        return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f %f",
                location.coordinate.latitude,
                location.coordinate.longitude];
    }

Answer (score 1):

Yes, saving latitude/longitude is the key here. If you try and save an address string, it'll be too error prone later to plot back onto the map.

You could just make a single string with the latitude followed by a comma and then the longitude. When you get this string back from your database later on then just split string by the comma. You can then use these values as latitude and longitude to create a CLLocation object or whatever object you need (MKAnnotation?)...

Hope that helps.